# How to get the below values using Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Can somebody help me in using Regex for the below expression:

`from:(seekingalpha O;from:selerity O;from:stocktwits O;from:yahoofinance O;from:cnnmoney O;from:marketwatch O;from:ibdinvestors O;from:thestreet);`

I need to get the following values:

```
seekingalpha;selerity;stocktwits;yahoofinance;  
cnnmoney;marketwatch;ibdinvestors;thestreet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the pattern seems predictable, I would use this: `([\w]+)[\s\)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try `((from)\:[\(]?([\w]*))` : group #3 catches the words you want

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a look-behind and grab all substrings after `from:`:

```
(?i)(?<=from:(?:\()?)[a-z]+
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fi)(%3f%3c%3dfrom%3a(%3f%3a%5c()%3f)%5ba-z%5d%2b&i=from%3a(seekingalpha+O%3bfrom%3aselerity+O%3bfrom%3astocktwits+O%3bfrom%3ayahoofinance+O%3bfrom%3acnnmoney+O%3bfrom%3amarketwatch+O%3bfrom%3aibdinvestors+O%3bfrom%3athestreet)%3b)

[image]